# Extract the part of the String Starting from special character c#

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to extract a part of the string starting from the character '-' . The String looks likes this Aaron,A-5767 I need to get just the 5767, that is extracting part of the string starting from the special character.

I understanding using the below substring function that selects from start of the string to any spl character

```
sub = str.Substring(0, index)
```

But how do start from spl the spl character

Comment: Have you tried using `IndexOf`?

Comment: Just `string.Split()` on the `-` character.

Comment: `sub = source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);`

Comment: What is `index`? Maybe you just have your parameters confused... `str.SubString(index);`

Comment: @Igor: too slow ;)

Comment: @musefan - I think that should cover it (between the 3 marked dups)...

Comment: @Igor: We can only hope it's enough...

Comment: @musefan int index = str.IndexOf('-');

Comment: @user4912134: Then you need to plus 1 to the index: `str.SubString(index + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you want an answer using Substring or whether you were just showing something you've tried to produce something similar...

An easy way however would be to use `split`:

```
String str = "Aaron,A-5767";
String[] array = str.split("-");
String left = array[0]; //Aaron,A
String right = array[1]; //5767
```